# nvd3 chart data from http

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js

Used this sample [plnkr ndv3 pie chart](http://plnkr.co/edit/vtKWU0?p=preview). It draws chart with static data as I hardcoded however **remote data is not getting apply into chart**, I can see it in log. Here is configuration

```
angular.module('codesApp.charts', ['nvd3'])
    .controller('ChartCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'pieChart',
                height: 500,
                x: function (d) {
                    return d.key;
                },
                y: function (d) {
                    return d.y;
                },
                showLabels: true,
                duration: 500,
                labelThreshold: 0.01,
                labelSunbeamLayout: true,
                legend: {
                    margin: {
                        top: 5,
                        right: 35,
                        bottom: 5,
                        left: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        $scope.data = [
            {
                "key": "DIRTYPE",
                "y": 15
            },
            {
                "key": "PL_TYPE",
                "y": 5
            }
        ];
        d3.json("./rest/codes/chartData", function (data1) {
            $scope.data = data1;
            console.log($scope.data);
        });
    });
```

Comment: `d3.json` won't make AngularJS check for changes. You need to add `$scope.$apply()` at the end of the callback passed as the second parameter of `d3.json`.

Comment: @LoremIpsum yeah, learnt that from answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're fetching data with `d3` you need to tell angular that the `$scope` has changed. You can do so through [`$appy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) call:

```
d3.json("./rest/codes/chartData", function (data1) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
       $scope.data = data1;
    });       
});
```

Or use angular's [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) like so:

```
$http.get("./rest/codes/chartData").then(function(response){
  $scope.data = response.data;
});
```